# railsで保存前に加工したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

以下のモデルを例にします。

### Post

- id
- name
- body

これにデータを追加するときは`Post.save(params)`とすればイケルと思いますが、
`Post.body`に独自の加工をほどこしたいのですがどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

モデルに`before_save`を使って書くと思うのですが、パラメータを加工して保存する場合、実際にはどのようなコードになるのでしょうか。

Comment: どういうパラメータをどのように加工して保存したいのでしょうか？ Post.save(params) のままだとなぜ困るのでしょうか？ そのあたりも追記してもらえると回答しやすいです。

Answer (score 2):

単純な加工の場合は、アクセサをオーバーライドします。

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def body=(param)
    data = do_something(param)
    write_attribute(:body, data)
  end
end

#do_somethingの中身が * 2 だったとすると
Post.new(body: "hoge") #=> #<Post id: nil, body: "hogehoge", ...>
```

参考 [Overwriting default accessors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)

他のカラムのデータに依存して編集したい場合、そのカラムの内容がアクセサが呼ばれた段階で反映されているかわからないので、うまくいきません。その場合はやはりコールバックを使うことになります。

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :update_body

  def update_title
    data = do_something(read_attribute(:body), read_attribute(:title))
    write_attribute(:body, data)
  end
end
```

ただし、コールバックは呼ばれない場合があったり、`before_save`だとsaveの度に呼ばれたりするので、注意が必要です。

コントローラで加工する方法もありますが、コントローラにロジックを書くのは好ましくないので、どうしてもコントローラでやらなければならない理由があるときだけにした方がよいでしょう。

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    attr = post_params
    attr[:body] = do_something(attr[:body])
    @post = Post.new(attr)
    post.save
  end
end
```